# graphics in right margin with caption

Tags: floats, marginpar

I want to place images in the right margin with a caption beneath them. I've looked at some of the questions and answers -- only one looked like my problem but when I copied the answer into my project it produced a figure in the middle of the text with the caption in the left margin. It included the package 'geometry' and a command `\floatsetup` that I'm convinced is the key to getting what I want. However, I could not find info on the command so I couldn't figure out how to change its parameters to get what I want. I started with the following, which made sense to me, but the compiler doesn't like it:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\marginpar{
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}
\caption{My pic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make you code compileable. Your caption for example is outside of the float. Also the `\marginpar` closes inside the figure float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
 \usepackage{graphicx,caption,lipsum}
  \begin{document} 
    \chapter{Test}
    \lipsum[1] \marginpar{\vspace{-3cm}\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{logoRS.png}\captionof{figure}{Logo}}  
  \end{document}
```

[image]

If you dont want 'Figure 1 Logo' but only 'Logo' edit the code this way:

```
\marginpar{\vspace{-3cm}\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{logoRS.png}\captionof*{figure}{Logo}}
```

(captionof starred).

[image]

Comment: Shiny! Thanks Raffaela.

Comment: @ TonyK My name is Raffaele. If you are happy with my answer, you could accept and up vote my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Happily. I clicked on the check mark in the left margin -- I think that's right.

Comment: Yes. Now you can click also on the big arrow on the left. Thanks.

Comment: Raffaele, I'm sorry about the scoring - I thought it was either 0 or 1. I didn't realize it could be higher. Your answer was perfect and deserved a higher score. Next time I'll be smarter.